# JDBC connection in JSP

Tags: java, oracle, jsp, jdbc

I had made my code to connect to Oracle Database to retrieve the data.

//Database Contents
Employee: 
        ID NAME                 DEPT

---

```
     1 Ghiridhar            IT
     2 Pabitra              Finance
     3 Sagar                Management
```

I also tried using only scriplet tag instead of all three tags. Then to  the outcome is the same.

JSP Code for JDBC Connection:

```
<%@page import="java.sql.*"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
</head>

<body>

//Declaration
   <%!
       Statement stmt = null;
       Connection con = null;
       ResultSet rs = null;
       StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
   %>

//JDBC Code
    <%
            try{  

Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");  

 con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe",
"system","system");  


 stmt=con.createStatement();  


 rs=stmt.executeQuery("select * from Employee");  

while(rs.next())  
{
out.println(rs.getInt(1)+"  "+rs.getString(2)+"  "+rs.getString(3));  
}

  stmt.execute("insert into Employee values(4,'John','Finance')");
  rs=stmt.executeQuery("select * from Employee");  

 while(rs.next())  
{
 sb.append(rs.getInt(1)+" "+rs.getString(2)+" "+rs.getString(3)); 
 sb.append("</UL>"); 
}

out.println(sb);
con.close();    
} //try block ends
catch(Exception e)
{ System.out.println(e);} 
    %>
//code ends
</body>
</html>
```

The output screen is blank. Please assist me in this issue.

Comment: Looks like you have an exception. Use correct logging and show us the full exception stakctrace. But seriously, don't put code like this in a JSP. Factor it out to a separate dao or service layer.

Comment: I am extremely sorry. But i forgot to add JAR file for oracle. Thank you for conveying me to keep an eye on log. I had executed it on Net beans which had shown the error as an info and i did not notice it.

Comment: Side note: do not do business logic in JSP; extract it to a class, and use either MVC pattern, or (at least) call the class from JSP. Much easier to maintain, and also to debug. And less tempting to write spaghetti-style code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never do like this. Don't open connection on jsp, it is bad form. You JSP mustn't contains java code. All java code should be in java classes, and if you want to make some logic on your jsp - use jstl library.